# Access Update not working

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I have an Access Database which links into Excel for a college database project. The goal is to fix incorrect/incomplete data before importation through the use of Update/SQL queries. There is one item in particular which is a field containing the order status. If an order is complete = Complete, if an order is missing a few parts = Backorder and nothing at all = Open. The issue I have is there is multiple parts on one PO ID# which makes it difficult to determine if an order is on backorder as 2/5 parts may be complete while 3/5 may be on backorder. Any ideas on how I can force access to automatically set a default order status or is this a long sql query?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by multiple parts? Can you show the relevant schema and what you have so far?

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/i5llhcaf7/

Comment: Basically each Purchase Order Number is tied to a POItemID which identifies which parts are ordered. When you expand the list you'll see a receiving history. What I'm trying to do is determine based on this if an order is complete, open (nothing received) or backorder (not completely received). When I do an Access Query and a Purchase Order Number has multiple item ids I haven't found a way to determine order status

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/yda9gdayr/ here is a better image. This order should be flagged as a backorder however the way access runs I dont think I can do this. Possible via SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With SQL you can return a query to find the order status, using a `CASE` statement. I'm not sure of the table/column names in the parent table you have but you can probably tweak it from here (I'm just assuming identity columns):

```
SELECT P.Id, P.Name, "Status" = 
    CASE
        WHEN R.QuantityReceived < I.QuantityOrdered THEN 'Backorder'
        WHEN R.QuantityReceived = I.QuantityOrdered THEN 'Complete'
        WHEN R.QuantityReceived > I.QuantityOrdered THEN 'Open'
    END
FROM PurchaseOrders P INNER JOIN POItem I on P.PurchaseOrderId = I.PurchaseOrderId
                      INNER JOIN POReceipt R on I.ItemId = R.ItemId
```

So first you need to join your tables to get the related records (this is also assuming that there is only one of each), then use a `CASE` statement to return the value you are looking for based on a comparison between fields.

Comment: Thanks Goose! I do have one table of each. (One with the PO #) (One with the POItem#) (One with the Receiving table) I'll switch Access to SQL view to do this and use CASE and it should get me started!